# Login failed for user 'sa' Reset password every day

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sa

Though it seems a very basic question but I am fed up with this problem. Every day I get `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Login failed for user 'sa'.`
Then I reset 'sa' password and my asp.net application starts working.
I have searched this error, almost every post says that its a lockout problem but no one suggests the solution. Please help.

Comment: You have set the option to block the user after some fail tries to login ! Remove this filter because someone try to login to the database (with wrong usename/pass) and block you out.

Comment: I don't have any option like this. I have even unchecked Enforce Password Policy check-box on Login Properties window for 'sa'. I have tried myself to login using wrong user name and password a 100 times but I don't get any 'sa' error

Answer (score 0):

The first, most dangerous, thing you're doing **wrong** is **using the sa account** for your asp.net application.

Set up a different account for your application. Grant it only the permissions it needs to function correctly.

And if your ASP.net application isn't getting the password wrong, which it almost certainly isn't, then something else is trying to connect to your SQL Server. Is it accessible to the outside world? You'll want to change that too.